# Created a PyPI package and it installs, but when run it returns an import error

Tags: python, pypi

I've created a simple package and was able to publish it in PyPI.
It's file struc is:

```
DaysGrounded\
DaysGrounded\setup.py
DaysGrounded\setup.cfg
DaysGrounded\requirements.txt
DaysGrounded\MANIFEST.in
DaysGrounded\daysgrounded\
DaysGrounded\daysgrounded\__init__.py
DaysGrounded\daysgrounded\__main__.py
DaysGrounded\daysgrounded\cli.py
DaysGrounded\daysgrounded\gui.py
DaysGrounded\daysgrounded\shared.py
```

I installed it in another machine and run c:\Python34\Scripts\daysgrounded.exe, but it returns the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 171, in _run_module_as_main
    "**main**", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\daysgrounded.exe__main__.py", line 5, in 
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\daysgrounded__main__.py", line 12, in 
    import cli
ImportError: No module named 'cli'

You can find the app in https://github.com/jcrmatos/DaysGrounded and
[https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=daysgrounded&version=0.0.8&:action=display](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=daysgrounded&version=0.0.8&%3aaction=display)

What am I doing wrong? Is it in setup.py?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,
                        unicode_literals)

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
#import py2exe

from daysgrounded import *

setup(
    name=__title__,
    version=__version__,

    description=__desc__,
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    #long_description=(read('README.txt') + '\n\n' +
    #                  read('CHANGES.txt') + '\n\n' +
    #                  read('AUTHORS.txt')),
    license=__license__,
    url=__url__,

    author=__author__,
    author_email=__email__,

    keywords=__keywords__,
    classifiers=__classifiers__,

    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests*']),
    #packages=__packages__,

    entry_points=__entrypoints__,
    install_requires=open('requirements.txt').read(),
    #install_requires=open('requirements.txt').read().splitlines(),

    include_package_data=True,
    package_data=__pkgdata__,

    #console=['daysgrounded\\__main__.py']
)


Or is it in __init__.py?

"""Manage child(s) grounded days."""

__all__ = [
    '__title__', '__version__',
    '__desc__', '__license__', '__url__',
    '__author__', '__email__',
    '__copyright__',
    '__keywords__', '__classifiers__',
    #'__packages__',
    '__entrypoints__', '__pkgdata__'
]

__title__ = 'daysgrounded'
__version__ = '0.0.8'

__desc__ = __doc__.strip()
__license__ = 'GNU General Public License v2 or later (GPLv2+)'
__url__ = 'https://github.com/jcrmatos/DaysGrounded'

__author__ = 'Joao Matos'
__email__ = 'jcrmatos@gmail.com'

__copyright__ = 'Copyright 2014 Joao Matos'

__keywords__ = 'days grounded'
__classifiers__ = [
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Environment :: Win32 (MS Windows)',
        'Intended Audience :: End Users/Desktop',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Natural Language :: Portuguese',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v2 or later (GPLv2+)',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Topic :: Other/Nonlisted Topic',
        # Use below to prevent any unwanted publishing
        #'Private :: Do Not Upload'
    ]

#__packages__ = ['daysgrounded']

__entrypoints__ = {
        'console_scripts': ['daysgrounded = daysgrounded.__main__:main'],
        #'gui_scripts': ['app_gui = daysgrounded.daysgrounded:start']
    }

__pkgdata__ = {'daysgrounded': ['*.txt']}
#__pkgdata__= {'': ['*.txt'], 'daysgrounded': ['*.txt']}
```

Thanks,

JM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the difference between the [three ways of invoking a python package](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html):

1. `python daysgrounded`
2. `python daysgrounded/__main__.py`
3. `python -m daysgrounded`

If you try each of these on your project you'll notice that the third method doesn't work, which is exactly the one `runpy` uses. The reason it doesn't work is because your `sys.path` is incorrect, because python adds `daysgrounded/` to your `sys.path` for the first two ways, but not the third.

In order for all three ways to work, you have to make sure that your sys.path is correct, and there are two ways of doing this.

If you want to be able to do `import cli`, `sys.path` should be `daysgrounded/`, which means you need to modify `__init__.py` to add it to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
import os.path
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

If you want to be able to do `from daysgrounded import cli`, `sys.path` should be the directory above `daysgrounded/`, which means you need to modify `__main__.py` to add it to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
import os.path
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.dirname(sys.path[0]))
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks. My app requires some text files that are located on the same directory. After the installation the program complains that it can't find the text files. They are in c:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\daysgrounded together with all the other files. How can I specify this default location, without using the complete path, to allow the app to work for people that install Python in another drive letter, for example? Thanks, JM

Comment: @jmatos Relative paths for `open()` etc. are relative with respect to the current working directory. If you want to be able to use relative paths, you have to change the current working directory with [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir) to where your module is (i.e. some variant of `sys.path[0]`, see main answer). The (better) alternative is to construct an absolute path from each relative path with respect to your module directory with [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).

Comment: Hello, Thanks. Instead I did this `
# set correct path to all data files
try:
    DATA_PATH = resource_filename(__name__, globalcfg.USAGE_FILE)
    DATA_PATH = DATA_PATH.replace(globalcfg.USAGE_FILE, '')
except:
    # if current module is frozen, use library.zip path
    if hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
        DATA_PATH = sys.prefix
        DATA_PATH.strip('/')
        DATA_PATH += '/'` This works for both "normal" and frozen builds. Every datafile is saved and read to/from the location where the module/exe is located, which is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @jmatos Where did you put the `DATA_PATH = ...` code? Is that in `setup.py` or `__init__.py`?